# C# WebSocket.SendAsync() randomly gets stuck

Tags: c#, wpf

I have used the following code to send using the System.Net.WebSocket from WPF after socket has connected

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sending...");
    await _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(packet.GetBytes()), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Sent...");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Calling code

```
            if (!ValidateSettings()) return;
            var hostname = TbHostname.Text.Trim();
            var tcpport = TbTcpPort.Text.Trim();

            _ws = new AchiWebSocket();
            _streamTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(async s =>
                {
                    var socket = (AchiWebSocket)s;
                    if (!_semaWs.Wait(0)) return;
                    UpdateBuffer();
                    var buffer = GetFrameBuffer();
                    var packet = new BinaryPacket(buffer.GetBytes());
                    if(socket.WebSocketState == null || socket.WebSocketState == WebSocketState.Closed)
                        await socket.Connect(new Uri("ws://" + hostname + "/superrfb"));
                    try
                    {
                        await socket.SendAsync(packet);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("--" + e.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _semaWs.Release();
                    }
                }, _ws, 0, 70);
```

Receiving Code (Asp.Net Core)

```
 public async Task StartReceiveAsync(Action<Packet> onReceive)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            var buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            do
            {
                result = await _ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                if (result.EndOfMessage)
                {
                    var packet = BinaryPacket.FromRaw(stream.ToArray());
                    onReceive.Invoke(packet);
                }
            }
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue);
            Dispose();
        }
```

I do receive some data but the socket gets stuck in SendAsync after a few packets. It doesn't return even after waiting several minutes.

[image]

Comment: How does the calling code look like ?  Are you using async / await all the way up ?

Comment: show more code....

Comment: Look at the other end of the wire to diagnose this problem.  If it is not  calling Receive() then your program will eventually get stuck when the TCP transmit buffer gets filled to capacity.

Comment: I have added the sending and receiving code. I'm receiving continuously in the loop, if the buffer gets filled, it should get empty in few receive calls.

Comment: I would bet that someone is disposing of the handle in some fashion and the failure stems from that..

Comment: Do you mean disposing the _streamTimer handle? i only dispose it when the stop button is pressed from UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. My onReceive.Invoke() function was throwing exception sometimes causing the server to stop receiving. This made the receive buffer fill up and WebSocket.SendAsync to stuck and wait until the buffer is free. After wrapping the onReceive.Invoke() in try catch, the code is working fine now.

```
try 
{
    onReceive.Invoke(packet);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: This is happening for a QueueClient (almost 25s delay) SendAsync with no receiver involved. I see 2 websocket traces with 101 status code happening.